# Problem install Arch Linux with RAID

Tags: arch-linux, boot, raid

I installed arch linux with RAID

But if I detach one of the two disks, the kernel cannot find the root partition, i give you a list of the most relevant files so you can help me find the cause of the problem.

The system is installed in Raid 1

this is /etc/fstab:
https://pastebin.com/2gW5Prmj

/etc/mdadm.conf:
https://pastebin.com/pPzBDHeK

/etc/default/grub:
https://pastebin.com/5h5n9ThJ

/etc/mkinitcpio.conf:
https://pastebin.com/bu4JE8qM

/boot/grub/grub.cfg:
https://pastebin.com/FAsQwDFD

lsblk command:
https://termbin.com/pzsa

I install the /boot in a separate partition as you can see in the output of lsblk

This is the error if i detach one of the two disk during boot process:

[image]

Comment: First of all: You are **NEVER supposed to remove a disk from a fully functional RAID!** This can lead to serious dataloss! On RAID or with RAID? RAID 0 or RAID 1? You need to give us more information if you expect anyone to be able to help you.

Comment: To add on to the above comment, if the disk you are detaching is part of a RAID which Arc is installed on; The expected result of detaching that disk mid-boot is exactly what happened here.